# More visible mouse point locator with multiple monitors

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, mouse

I have the "Show location of pointer when I press CTRL key" option on in Mouse Properties to help me find my mouse pointer. This however is not enough as I have a 4 monitor setup and if the mouse is somewhere in the periphery, the mouse locator circle barely registers. Is there something I can do to make the pointer locator more visible? I am thinking big huge thick pulsating reticles that show where my mouse could be hiding. Googling for software brings back rather sketchy results.

Thanks!

Comment: Superusers, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is super old, but I ran across it trying to solve the same problem (four monitors in a 2x2 configuration).

Best solution I've found so far is [multi-monitor mouse](http://lifehacker.com/5159970/multi-monitor-mouse-snaps-your-cursor-around-multiple-screens) which has a hotkey for jumping the mouse to specific monitors.  I about to set it up for just one hotkey: jump the mouse to my primary monitor; forget looking for it, make it be here!

Comment: "forget looking for it, make it be here!" This is the correct way to think about the problem. Unfortunately my needs from 2012 have changed. I now need a solution for bringing my mouse to me on a multi monitor OSX setup... ;)

Comment: Alas, can't help you there (and MMM doesn't have the keybind I said I was going to make: all the sads).